# Java SimpleDateFormat not working

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I am displaying the date and time in Android with this format:
2015-11-25 23:25:00

How can I change it to the following format?
2015-11-25

I wrote some code ,but not working correctly.

```
    public static Date toDate(boolean isCurrentDate, String dateString) {
    Date date=null;
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    try {
        if (isCurrentDate)
            date = new Date();
        else
            date = formatter.parse(dateString);
        System.err.println("Printresult" + formatter.parse(formatter.format(date)));

    } catch (ParseException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.err.println("Printresult2" + date.toString());
    return date;
}
```

I log and result is like this

```
Wed Nov 25 00:00:00 GMT+00:00 2015
```

How i can change date format  like this : ? (2015-11-25)

Comment: why `System.err.println()` ?? there is Log.v() or `System.out.println()`

Comment: change `formatter.parse(formatter.format(date))` to `formatter.format(date)` :-)

Comment: I tried it but return data's format is like this  Wed Nov 25 00:00:00 GMT+00:00 2015 @Rahul Kumar

Comment: does the `ParseException` gets printed?

Answer (score 1):

You need one format for parsing and another for printing if the formats differ.

The following code deals with displaying the date in the format you want.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
System.out.println(sdf.format(date));
```

You could alter the beheviour of `toString()` method by using anonymous class and overrriding `toString()` method or just create named class deriving from `Date`, but there is no point to do it.

Comment: Thanks your attention. My goal is to change date format and return current date with changed format. How I can solved it? I debuged and result was a same @Yoda

Comment: @BekaKK You can't set format for a `Date` object its `toString() `method will always return the string according to one format, but you can display it according to the format using `SimpleDateFormat` object and its `format()` method.